# How to open a Website in Google Chrome with Autoit

Tags: google-chrome, automation, web, autoit

I just started using Autoit and i want to make a script that open a New Tab in Google Chrome and visit a Website. If Google Chrome is not running in the PC then the Script should Run Google Chrome and visit the Website.
I know how to do it this way but if the resolution of the Screen change then the Script is not going to work

```
Run ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
Sleep (2000)
Send ("http://google.com")
Send ("{enter}")
```

Also this code can't see if the Google Chrome is running it just run a new one.
Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Run ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe [desired website]")`
```

For example:

```
Run ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe https://google.com")`
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use a shell command.

The following command can be used to do it!

```
ShellExecute("chrome.exe", "https://talkjarvis.com --new-window --start-fullscreen")
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a new Windows you can use:

```
chrome --new-window www.google.com
```